# Map format YY.MM date time to MM.YYYY date time

Tags: c#, datetime, converters

In database I have a string that represent a date time that format is `YY.MM` (`YY` it means *Year* and `MM` is *Month*. for example `21.03 = 2021.03`)

How can I map this special `format(yy.mm)` to this `format(mm/yyyy)` by using data annotation or another way ?

Comment: What did you try? if its a string, it sounds like it should be mighty simple..

Comment: If you don't have a special reason, do _not_ keep your `DateTime` values as a `string` in your database.This is a bad habit. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type On the other hand, your question is not clear at all. Can you please read [ask] a few times, maybe? If you asking parsing it to DateTime in C# side, you can use `yyyy.MM` format with `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` methods with proper culture. Also be aware the case sensitive issues. `MM` is for months but `mm` is for minutes.

Comment: This database is not my own! I don't allow to edit it!

Comment: 19.12 is this 2019.12 or 1912.12 
How can you identify that?

Comment: @SanuAntony: You can suppose that only 2019 is correct.

Comment: @Jahan Just use a string split then and format the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Parse` date and then format back to the `string`:

```
  using System.Globalization;

  ...

  string source = "21.03";

  // 03.2021
  string result = DateTime
    .ParseExact(source, "yy'.'MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    .ToString("MM'.'yyyy");
```

However, we have an *ambiguity* here: `"03.50"` can be either `"March 1950"` or `"March 2050"`. The default policy is `00..29` to `2000..2029` and `30..99` to `1930..1999` if you want to change this policy you can create and use your own *culture*:

```
  CultureInfo myCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

  // Everything to 20.., never 19..
  myCulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099;

  string source = "99.03";
  // 03.2099
  string result = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "yy'.'MM", myCulture).ToString("MM'.'yyyy");
```

Or even

```
  CultureInfo myCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

  // Everything to 20.., never 19..
  myCulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax = 2099;

  // Current culture as usual, except 2 digit year policy
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = myCulture;

  ...

  string source = "99.03";
  // 03.2099
  string result = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "yy'.'MM", null).ToString("MM'.'yyyy");
```

Comment: Thanks! And how can I compare two date time in terms of type of format? for example if I have "MM.YYYY", I don't want to parse the date time.

Comment: @Jahan: when working with *date*, please use `DateTime` class which has been *specially designed* for this: `Parse[Exact]` is just one line and then you can put an easy to read `if ((date1 == date2) && (date2 < date3)) {...}` without complex and prone to error `string` manipulations. Read `string` from RDBMS,  Parse it to `DateTime`, perform all business logic and, finally, format it back to `String` if required.

Comment: Upvoted for describing `.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using the string split function:

```
string dateIn = "11.10";
string month = dateIn.Split('.')[1]; //split the String at the point and save it
string year = dateIn.Split('.')[0];
string dateOut = $"{month}/20{year}";   //build a new string         

//this will fix the 1900/2000 issue more or less as all dates in the furutre would be send back to the past  you can adapt this to your need:
if( DateTime.Now.Year < Convert.ToInt32($"20{year}"))
{
    dateOut = $"{month}/19{year}";
}
//dateOut is "10/2011"
```

Comment: Microsoft standard for 1900/2000 ambiguity seems be to cut on years 29/30. https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/change-the-date-system-format-or-two-digit-year-interpretation-aaa2159b-4ae8-4651-8bce-d4707bc9fb9f. But your algorithm is fine if the database only contains past dates.

Comment: Anyway, it will change soon (as we are in 2019). And from Win 7 you can change that in Regional Settings.